# Can I Modify Hibernate/JPA Attribute Dynamically?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an Entity that has a column that I need to make Transient only for a specific configuration or session factory.  Basically, the column should never be sent in an update or insert statement for one particular configuration, and will be set by an interceptor when retrieving data.  For any other configuration, the column should be persisted in the database.  Is there any way to configure a column at runtime/dynamically, based on the session factory or configuration?  I am able to make the column transient and set it correctly, but I need it persisted for some configurations.

*EDIT* I initially put "filter" but meant "interceptor"

[image]

Comment: Can you live with inserting nulls in configurations you don't want it persisted? You could set it to null in an interceptor for those configurations.

Answer (score 1):

An annotation is a form of syntactic metadata that can be added to Java source code so you cannot change in it at run-time.

However, if its necessary, then java annotations, can be accessible to the programmer at the runtime through reflection api. An example on how to add annotations using Javassist is [here](http://ayoubelabbassi.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/how-to-add-annotations-at-runtime-to.html).

My recommendation, as Dragan suggest, is that you can set it to null wherever its not required.

Comment: Setting the field to null would still cause it to be sent over when hibernate persists the object, though, no?

Comment: Let's suppose that you've made that particular column transient. Now when you'll insert it into your database, the table's structure isn't going to change. You can insert data like this into a new table if you don't want that particular column in your database. That's why I think that a functionality like this isn't supplied along with hibernate. Please inform me if you think I'm missing somewhere.

Comment: I created a schema diagram to hopefully explain this better :).  I know it's not perfect, but it might make my intentions clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can create two entities, as mapping of one table. In first one you column would be transient in another will not. I've already had some trouble like this, and i think that it is not possible to change mapping config after you have opened the session.