# How to ignore updatable = false annotation?

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate

If a field is annotated `updatable=false`, the column will not be included in SQL UPDATE.

This is desired default behavior. But in one specific flow, I need to update this this column. Is there a way to ignore this annotation? Or do I need to DELETE and INSERT entry?

```
@Column(name = "client_rating", updatable = false)
private Integer clientRating;
```

Comment: You can always do a raw query; ugly, but it would work.  I couldn't find a duplicate for this, hence I have upvoted you.

Comment: Thank you for the upvote and answer. I've spend some time finding an answer to this question, yet no luck.
A raw query isn't the most elegant option, but it's still an option. I'll try that if I can't find a way to ignore the annotation.

Comment: There might be another (ugly) option: create a subclass of your entity with `@AttributeOverrides` which is only useable for the specific case.

Comment: Since Annotations are kind of syntactic metadata, you cannot modify them at runtime. I found this which seems related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35256140/can-i-modify-hibernate-jpa-attribute-dynamically

Comment: @Thomas, I don't think that option is all too ugly. Using a subclass and `@AttributeOverrides` feels to me like a cleaner and better to read option. After reading @S.K. link, I'm starting to think that this is also the best option.

Thanks a bunch for the answers!